# Checking Pandas column value contains in a list and assigning a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and a list with certain values.
I want to check whether each column value under a column header is contained   in the list and want to assign 1 if it is found else 0.
In the below example , the column values under column header v is tested   against the values in the list l.

```
l=['a','e']  
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],'v' : ['a','b','c','d','e']})  
df  

id  v
 1  a
 2  b
 3  c
 4  d
 5  e
```

Result , I am expecting is,

```
id  v  
 1  1  
 2  0  
 3  0  
 4  0  
 5  1
```

I tried using

```
df['v'] = df['v'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(l))
```

but unable to proceed how to assign the value 1 and 0

Answer (score 9):

`df.v.isin(l)` will give you a boolean Series:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: v, dtype: bool
```

You can convert it into zeros and ones using `astype`:

`df.v.isin(l).astype(int)`

```
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
Name: v, dtype: int32
```